# VTK rendering 2D mesh in python

Tags: python, mesh, vtk

so i'm trying to render a 2D mesh using vtk (in python). I have a list 
of tuples containing all the points and also a list of tuples containing the 
points of each cell. Just to experiment, I tried to create a polydata object 
of a square with 4 elements and render it, but i ended up with this:

[image: square]

I would like it to show the lines connecting the nodes (like a wireframe) 
instead of solid square.. 
This is the code to produce the image above:

```
def main2():

    #Array of vectors containing the coordinates of each point
    nodes = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0], [2, 2, 0], 
                      [1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]])

    #Array of tuples containing the nodes correspondent of each element
    elements = np.array([(0, 1, 8, 7), (7, 8, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3, 8), (8, 3, 4, 
                        5)])

    #Make the building blocks of polyData attributes
    Mesh = vtk.vtkPolyData()
    Points = vtk.vtkPoints()
    Cells = vtk.vtkCellArray()  

    #Load the point and cell's attributes
    for i in range(len(nodes)):
        Points.InsertPoint(i, nodes[i])

    for i in range(len(elements)):
        Cells.InsertNextCell(mkVtkIdList(elements[i]))

    #Assign pieces to vtkPolyData
    Mesh.SetPoints(Points)
    Mesh.SetPolys(Cells)

    #Mapping the whole thing
    MeshMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    if vtk.VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5:
        MeshMapper.SetInput(Mesh)
    else:
        MeshMapper.SetInputData(Mesh)

    #Create an actor
    MeshActor = vtk.vtkActor()
    MeshActor.SetMapper(MeshMapper)

    #Rendering Stuff
    camera = vtk.vtkCamera()
    camera.SetPosition(1,1,1)
    camera.SetFocalPoint(0,0,0)

    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    renWin   = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    renWin.AddRenderer(renderer)

    iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

    renderer.AddActor(MeshActor)
    renderer.SetActiveCamera(camera)
    renderer.ResetCamera()
    renderer.SetBackground(1,1,1)

    renWin.SetSize(300,300)

    #Interact with data
    renWin.Render()
    iren.Start()


main2()
```

I would also like to know if it's possible to have a gridline as the 
background of the render window, instead of a black color, just like this:

[image: gridline]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MeshActor.GetProperty().SetRepresentationToWireframe() (https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkProperty.html#a2a4bdf2f46dc499ead4011024eddde5c) to render the actor as wireframe, or MeshActor.GetProperty().SetEdgeVisibility(True) to render it as solid with edges rendered as lines.

Regarding the render window background, I don't know.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by adding the following lines:
 `self.MeshActor.GetProperty().EdgeVisibilityOn()`
 `self.MeshActor.GetProperty().SetColor(colors.GetColor3d("Red"))`
 `self.MeshActor.GetProperty().SetEdgeColor(colors.GetColor3d("Black"))`

But thanks anyway! Btw do you know how i can disable the rotation of the actor? Because as i'm rendering a 2D image, i would like it to stay 2D.

Cheers

Comment: Camera behaviour is managed by "interactor style" of the vtkRenderWindowInteractor (called "iren" in your code), you can get it/set it through iren.GetInteractorStyle. The default i think is vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera (https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.html). You can try looking at all the derived classes from vtkInteractorStyle (https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkInteractorStyle.html) if you find one that you like better or create your own one that behaves the way you want and than set it by iren.SetInteractorStyle.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MafiaSkafia I created what I was looking for, 2D grid for 3D purposes, maybe someone will be looking for something like this too.

```
# plane
planeSource = vtk.vtkPlaneSource()
planeSource.SetOrigin(-100.0, -100.0, 0.0)
# planeSource.SetNormal(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
planeSource.SetResolution(100,100)
planeSource.SetPoint1(100.0,-100.0,0.0)
planeSource.SetPoint2(-100.0,100.0,0.0)
planeSource.Update()

plane = planeSource.GetOutput()

# Create a mapper and actor
mapperP = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapperP.SetInputData(plane)

actorP = vtk.vtkActor()
actorP.SetMapper(mapperP)
actorP.GetProperty().SetColor(0,0,0)
actorP.GetProperty().EdgeVisibilityOn() # showing mesh
actorP.GetProperty().SetEdgeColor(1,1,1)
actorP.GetProperty().SetOpacity(0.2) # transparency
...
renderer.AddActor(actorP)
```

[image]